# Using CLLocationDistance to calculate the outermost coordinates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am placing 1-12 placemarks on my map. I am having trouble calculating the two outermost points so that I can zoom the map out to show all the pins.

```
CLLocationDistance distLong = [zoomLocationMax.longitude getDistanceFrom:zoomLocationMin.longitude];
CLLocationDistance distLat = [zoomLocationMax.latitude getDistanceFrom:zoomLocationMin.latitude];

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(m_MapView.userLocation.coordinate, distLat, distLong);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [m_MapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

m_MapView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[m_MapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

I have been fooling with the above code but I can foresee some issues:

1) The first two lines give me a Bad receiver type 'CLLocationDegres' (aka double'} error.
2) I do not really want the users location as the center point, I would ideally like to have the center of the two farthest points.

Any code snippet, example or explanation would greatly help!!

Thank you

Edit to show how zoomLocatin was calculated.  I basically take the log and lat and determine the min and max... not sure if that is right either:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocationMin;
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocationMax;
if (coordinate.latitude < zoomLocationMin.latitude)
    zoomLocationMin.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
if (coordinate.longitude < zoomLocationMin.longitude)
    zoomLocationMin.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
if (coordinate.latitude > zoomLocationMax.latitude)
    zoomLocationMax.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
if (coordinate.longitude > zoomLocationMax.longitude)
    zoomLocationMax.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this code to handle perfect fit for your placemarks :

```
- (void)zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView animated:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    NSArray *annotations = mapView.annotations;
    int count = [mapView.annotations count];
    if ( count == 0) { return; } //return if no annotations

    //convert NSArray of id <MKAnnotation> into an MKCoordinateRegion that can be used to set the map size
    //can't use NSArray with MKMapPoint because MKMapPoint is not an id
    MKMapPoint points[count]; //C array of MKMapPoint struct
    for( int i=0; i<count; i++ ) //load points C array by converting coordinates to points
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [(id <MKAnnotation>)[annotations objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];
        points[i] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);
    }
    //create MKMapRect from array of MKMapPoint
    MKMapRect mapRect = [[MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:count] boundingMapRect];
    //convert MKCoordinateRegion from MKMapRect
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);

    //add padding so pins aren't scrunched on the edges
    region.span.latitudeDelta  *= ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR;
    region.span.longitudeDelta *= ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR;
    //but padding can't be bigger than the world
    if( region.span.latitudeDelta > MAX_DEGREES_ARC ) { region.span.latitudeDelta  = MAX_DEGREES_ARC; }
    if( region.span.longitudeDelta > MAX_DEGREES_ARC ){ region.span.longitudeDelta = MAX_DEGREES_ARC; }

    //and don't zoom in stupid-close on small samples
    if( region.span.latitudeDelta  < MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC ) { region.span.latitudeDelta  = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC; }
    if( region.span.longitudeDelta < MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC ) { region.span.longitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC; }
    //and if there is a sample of 1 we want the max zoom-in instead of max zoom-out
    if( count == 1 )
    { 
        region.span.latitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC;
    }
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:animated];
}
```

So, you have to define the Padding, Maximum degree arc and Minimum zoom arc. For Ex. should belike this :

```
#define MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC 0.05 //approximately 1 miles (1 degree of arc ~= 69 miles)
#define ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR 1.25
#define MAX_DEGREES_ARC 360
```

Hopefully, You will like it, Cheers